# android:digits not working with _ and ,

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to allow only letters, numbers,  and _ in a edittext.

So I added:

```
android:digits="0123456789,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,_, "
```

the problem is it allows sometimes `,`.

And only allow `_` if I type it in my real keyboard, but not in android keyboard.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: it will accept `,` as you have it in your digits...try use: `android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,_, "`

Comment: Your physical keyboard is assigned a profile by the OS when it is connected. If it can't find a specific profile, it will use a generic one. This assignment process can be observed in the log file, and by going into Settings to verify what profile it was assigned. There may be a chance that some profiles don't work with the android:digits attribute.

Comment: android:maxLines ="1" not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your string to the following:

```
android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_ "
```

**UPDATE:**

I added a "text filter" (FilterFormatted) to the edit text and found that it will only fire for the characters specified/allowed in android:digits (I apologize my solution is in monodroid so requires translation, but it's a start. I'd look into using a regular expression with your Input Filter to meet all your requirements, digits alone is probably not sufficient if it doesn't allow for whitespace).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:digits="0123456789qwert_">
    <!--android:inputType="textFilter"-->
  </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

[Activity(Label = "LifeCycles", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity, IInputFilter
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        EditText et = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edit_text_1);
        et.SetFilters(new[] { (Android.Text.IInputFilter)this });            
    }        

    public ICharSequence FilterFormatted(ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        // no log entry when non android:digit keys pressed...
        Android.Util.Log.Info("EDIT_TEXT_FILTER","start...");

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            if (Character.IsWhitespace(source.CharAt(i)))
            {
                //return "";
                new Java.Lang.String(" ");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this string I still cant get spaces to work (which I thought the trailing space character allowed), but everything else seems ok... I'll going to grab a physical keyboard to test as well.

Comment: ...same results for hard and soft keyboards; all specified characters accepted except for " " (space-bar).